# Why should I explicitly pass typename to std::forward?

Tags: c++, templates, forward

Why is it necessary to explicitly indicate the type of template argument in std::forward?

```
template <class T> void foo (T&& x) {
    goo (x);                   // always an lvalue
    goo (std::forward<T>(x));  // rvalue if argument is rvalue
}
```

considering *std::forward implementation*:

```
template <typename T>
T&& forward(std::remove_reference_t<T>& x)
{
    return static_cast<T&&>(x);
}
```

and *std::remove_reference implementation*:

```
template< class T > struct remove_reference      {typedef T type;};
template< class T > struct remove_reference<T&>  {typedef T type;};

template< class T >
using remove_reference_t = typename remove_reference<T>::type;
```

Comment: Are you asking what is it about the implementation that makes the type argument mandatory, as opposed to deduce? Or why is it required as a design choice?

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica I'm trying to figure out why I can't write just `goo (std::forward(x));`

Comment: Because `forward` cannot deduce the type. In case of universal references, `f(T&&)`, the type `T` is actually the type of reference you call the function with. The `&&` is purely symbolic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument's type in `std::forward()` is:

```cpp
remove_reference<T>::type
```

Here `T` position is left of the scope resolution operator `::`, which makes it a "non-deduced context" (see [non-deduced context on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Non-deduced_contexts)). Because it is not automatically deduced, you have to provide the type yourself.